# Use solver in loop (Use VBA or other available method)

Tags: vba, excel, loops, solver

I am trying to use solver to find the root for 182 cells, each cell is depend only on one another variable, the output cell is from O2 to O183, the variable cell is from P2 to P183. 
I am trying to change the variable cells to have the output cell equal to 1.
I tried to use VBA but it failed multiple times:

```
Sub epsilon()
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Do
SolverReset
SolverOptions precision:=0.0001
SolverOK SetCell:=Cells(i, 15).Value, _
    ValueOf:="1", _
    byChange:=Cells(i, 16).Value
    SolverSolve userFinish:=True
i = i + 1
Loop Until i = 184
End Sub
```

The error "unexpected error (35010)" occurs and I am not sure if I write this solver VBA correct. Anyone can help?

Comment: As far as I rember you can only have one solver definition per worksheet so the loop cannot work.

Comment: downgraded for repeating question

Answer (score 0):

maybe this [vba loop](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html) can help to solved your problem.